# Articles not collapsing

Tags: php, css, wordpress, masonry

I am currently developing a Wordpress theme.

The problem I am facing is the following:

Articles do not collapse as they should.

PHP & HTML

```
<script> 
  /* adds classes based on image orientation */
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("article:has(.landscape)").addClass( "l-article");
    $("article:has(.portrait)").addClass( "p-article");
  });
</script>
<div class="blog-list container">
  <div class="row grid index-pos">  
    <?php 
       /* wp loop */
    ?>
      /* article that doesn't collapse well */
      <article class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">     
          <?php image_filter($size) ; ?> /* displays wp thumbnail with class .landscape for landscape and .portrait for portrait
        </a>
        <div class="item-holder">
          /* code that shows title and excerpt
        </div>
      </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
article .portrait {
    height: 833px;
}
article .landscape {    
    height: 300px;
}
.l-article {
    height: 530px;
}
.p-article {
    height: 1100px;
}
col.*.* { float:left }
```

[image showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D8lC.jpg)

What is causing the issue?

I have tried using masonry from [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/) but it doesn't do the job in terms of aligning the images well together.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `.hasClass()` instead?

Comment: Anyways, might want to look into flexbox.